# How does cnosdb remove nodes?

Tags: cnosdb

I am deploying a multi-machine cluster using cnosdb. After running the cluster for a period of time, some of the machines need to be repaired. At this time, I need to remove the cnosdb nodes on the machine and ensure that the data is not lost. Do you need to manually migrate data files to another machine? How do you ensure that data is not duplicated or lost? Are there any automated scripts or tools you can use?